# WildFly 14 missing modules : org/apache/commons/configuration

Tags: wildfly, jboss7.x, apache-commons-config, wildfly-11, jboss-modules

WildFly 14 is missing the org/apache/commons/configuration module in the package , same for wildfly 15.

Is this removed from wildfly distributions for some reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was removed in WildFly 9 as far as I can tell, https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/pull/7297. You'll need to include the dependency in your deployment if you require it.